# Retrieve multiple value of a <a href> tag using php

Tags: php

I need to extract the link value which is stored in a `<a>` tag by using php code.

I used below code

```
$url = '<a title="Question" href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask">t</a>';
preg_match("/href=\"(.*?)\"/i", $url, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

With the above code I can able to get the value of a single href. But it is not working for  multiple href in a string(i.e `$url = '<a title="Question" href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask">t</a><a href="x.php">x</a>';)`. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/preg_match_all) to get all the matches, not just the first.

```
$url = '<a title="Question" href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask">t</a>&nbsp;<a href="x.php">x</a>';
preg_match_all("/href=\"(.*?)\"/i", $url, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: one more thing if we need to get href and an identifier class (ie <a href="" class="fb"></a>).i need to get href of class fb url means

Answer (score 1):

Use a DOM parser, this example should get you going:

```
<?php
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML('<a title="Question" href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask">t</a>');

$elm = $doc->getElementsByTagName('a')->item(0);

foreach ($elm->attributes as $attr) {
    echo $attr->name . ' ' . $attr->value . '<br>';
}

echo "Directly getting href: " . $elm->attributes->getNamedItem('href')->value;
```

Output:

```
title Question
href http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask
Directly getting href: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask
```

Demo: http://viper-7.com/EN1Usi

Docs: http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php